# Finding unused functions in C++ codes for Testing coverage

Tags: c++, code-coverage, static-analysis

i'm looking for a **Static analysis tool** which can find unused functions with this kind of situation.

```
void A(void)
{
    //do something
}

void B(void)
{
    A();
}
void C(void)
{
    B();
}

int main(void)
{
    //doesn't call A(), B(), C()
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, i want to know that **function A, B, C all of them are not used**., and some tools say function B, C is used somewhere.

I want this result as raw data which can reuse at **Bullseye** for function coverage analysis. Our project runs at Windows 7, **Visual studio 2015/ARMcc**(not sure about the details for ARM build). Tools with free for business license would be perfect.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: "testing coverage"  "static analysis" - so... you want a tool that tells you what functions are being exercised by your tests without running them? Why?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Gotta get used to things here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a external tool, your compiler can do that for you.

If you declare your function as `static` (or use an anonymous namespace) the compiler can figure it out with the coresponding compiler flags (`-Wunused-function`).

```
prog.c:10:13: warning: unused function 'C' [-Wunused-function]
static void C(void)
```

Comment: The problem of the OP (I think) is that the compiler won't report `B` or `A` as unused as well. A full static analysis tool should be able to pick it up though.

Comment: My compiler (clang) can do that as well as soon as I remove `C` it marks `B` as unused and after that `A` as well. Yes it is a bit tedious, but it works ;)